# Apache mod_wsgi error: Forbidden

Tags: django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi

I am trying to configure mod_wsgi on Apache to work with SSL certificate.

This is 403 error that I am getting when I access `https://servername.com`

`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

This is how my apache configuration file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName servername.com
        ServerAlias www.servername.com

        # Django Application
        Alias /static /root/www/static
        <Directory /root/www/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /root/www/appname/apache>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess appname python-path=/root/www:/root/www/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup appname
        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/www/appname/apache/wsgi.py

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/appname/appname.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/appname/appname.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/appname/intermediate.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my folder structure with permissions:

```
/root/www/
drwxr-xr-x   9 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 23 18:33 www

/root/www/appname
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 24 09:15 appname

cd /root/www/appname
ls -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data       0 Jul 25  2015 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data    4096 Mar 21 10:54 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root        4096 Mar 24 09:15 apache
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    5199 Mar 24 08:50 settings.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    4504 Mar 18 06:14 urls.py

cd /root/www/appname/apache
ls -la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        0 Mar 24 09:15 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      395 Mar 24 09:15 wsgi.py
```

Can someone see a problem here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing execute permission on the every folder in the path.

I solved it with adding it.

```
chmod +x /root
chmod +x /root/www
chmod -R +x /root/www/appname
```